# How to redirect in php with customized url

Tags: php

I need to write a php  page that opens an existing url with customized query strings (essentially redirect).

```
"http://existingurl?test=pass&newparam=".$_REQUEST['u'];
```

How to do that?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you having problems? PHP's `header()` function normally handles redirects.

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```
<?php

header('Location: http://existingurl?test=pass&newparam='.urlencode($_REQUEST['u']));
exit();

?>
```

Comment: Don't we need to urlencode `$_REQUEST['u']` here?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use the header function.
Don't forget to use urlencode to secure the user input comming from $_REQUEST['u'].

```
<?php
    header('Location: http://existingurl?test=pass&newparam='.urlencode($_REQUEST['u']));
    exit();
?>
```

For more information, next time you can check the official documentation.
http://php.net/manual/fr/function.header.php

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Location: http://existingurl?test=pass&newparam='.urlencode($_REQUEST['u']));
die();
```

If you perhaps mean that you need to build a Query string with more than one parameter from your POST/GET request you might need to look at [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) and append it to the url